# a question on topological manifolds and what topology provides

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

When one talks of a topological manifold being locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is it meant that the topology of the manifold is locally identical to a Euclidean topology such that we can represent points on the manifold (locally) in the same manner that we can for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e. as  $n$-tuples of real numbers?

I must admit I find the whole concept of topology quite confusing, I've read things such as "a topology on a manifold endows it with a primitive notion of geometrical structure without the need to introduce the notion of a metric etc." What exactly is meant by this?
In physics, particularly general relativity, space time is taken as a topological manifold, and I know that the manifold has a topology defined on it is key, but I don't really understand the conceptual significance of it?

Comment: Indeed in physics you have differentiable manifolds (which are also topological manifolds but carry more structure).

Answer (score 1):

In physics one works with coordinate systems all the time, and one changes coordinate systems all the time.

Before relativity theory, in the Newtonian universe, it seemed that space might have one more-or-less unique  "natural" coordinate system, making space a real-life copy of the mathematical abstraction $\mathbb{R}^3$ --- unique, that is, up to translation and rotation of coordinates, and up to uniform expansion of coordinates which amounts to a choice of unit distance.

After relativity no-one expects this kind of uniqueness of coordinate systems anymore. Nonetheless, space-time coordinate systems still remain a key tool of (non-quantum-mechanical) physics.

So how do you speak about space-time if you don't have just one gigantic global natural coordinate system? Well you speak about it as patching together zillions of small scale coordinate systems, which might or might not be natural in some "local" sense. But to patch together coordinate systems like that, you need a mathematical theory, and that's precisely what topology gives you.

Space-time is a topological space, which gives it a structure of "nearness" in a rather coarse sense, or you can think of it as a structure of "convergent sequences", and there are various other ways that we use our intuition to understand topological spaces in general. Mathematically, you are simply specifying what subsets are "open", and you are specifying a few rock bottom axioms that open sets should satisfy (see the definition of a topology).

Next, space-time has coordinate systems; the rock-bottom minimum feature is that the coordinate systems are given by homeomorphisms $\phi : U \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ where $U$ is an open subset of space-time and $V$ is an open subset of the coordinate space $\mathbb{R}^4$. The set of domains $U$ for these coordinate systems should cover all of space-time. Open-ness is important for many reasons, the most basic theoretical reason being that multivariable calculus only really makes sense when working with functions whose domains are open subsets of Euclidean space.

Next, although space-time coordinate systems are not assumed to be "unique" or "natural", nonetheless if you have two space-time coordinate systems on overlapping open sets $U_1,U_2$ it **is** required that the overlap map between those two systems be nice in some manner. The domain of the overlap map is $\phi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$ which is an open subset of $V_1$ and therefore an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, its range is $\phi_2(U_1 \cap U_2)$ which is an open subset $V_2$ and therefore an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, and the formula for this map is $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}$. Again the rock bottom minimum requirement on this overlap map is that it be infinitely differentiable, meaning all partial derivatives of all orders exist at all points (here is where open-ness is most important, in order to apply the tools of multivariable calculus).

Next, depending on what portion of physics you are working in, you will want to have still more structure on your coordinate systems, and your overlap maps should respect this structure. For instance in general relativity you want the extra structure of various tensors such as a Lorentz metric and a stress-energy tensor, and so on.

Comment: So is the main point of defining a topology on a manifold to make it possible to create overlapping open subsets of the manifold that can be mapped locally to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: In a sense, yes. The topology on the manifold guarantees that those overlap maps (aka coordinate change maps) are continuous. Further structure on those maps, such as differentiability, or having an invariant tensor of some kind, is then imposed depending on what part of physical or mathematical theory you are working on.

Comment: I'm studying it in relation to general relativity. Is the topology required also so that one can "stitch together" neighbouring open subsets to reconstruct the manifold (such that the manifold can be constructed from local patches of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that's also a good way to look at it. One way to formalize this "stitching together" process is to use the concept of a "quotient topology". You can see this kind of "stitching together" being carried out in topology books, where for instance the torus $S^1 \times S^1$ is obtained from a square by stitching sides together appropriately. Usually, though, what one does in studying a differentiable manifold is to just start with the assumption that the space in question is a topological space, and then add further conditions to the overlap maps such as differentiability.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I think it's starting to become a little clearer now. Would it be correct to say that the geometry of a manifold does not exist until one has defined a metric on it?

Comment: Yes, that is completely correct. On a space-time coordinate chart, before one has the stress-energy tensor, or the metric, or even before one has the "light cone" structure, one just has a differentiable manifold. With that structure you can say what a smooth path is, but you cannot yet tell how long it is, not until the metric is imposed.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, I think it's starting to become a little clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that a topological space $X$ is a topological manifold being locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for each $x\in X$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ with a continuous function $\phi_U:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi_U$ induces an homeomorphism between $U$ and $\phi_U(U)$. This is the ground definition. The $(U,\phi_U)$ are called charts.

Now one usually requires additional "properties" (they are quite technical, in most cases they are obvious) namely the topology on $X$ should be Hausdorff and countable at infinity.

The idea behind your quote is (IMO) that generally you just don't want to work with "topological" manifold but you want to work on "differentiable" manifold or "holomorphic" manifold (to name but a few). Now those additional structures are quite hard to define out of nowhere.

If $X$ is a topological manifold with a set of charts $\{(U,\phi_U)\}$ we say that they define a "differentiable" manifold if for any chart $U,V$ such that $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$ we have that :

$$\phi_U\circ\phi_V^{-1}:\phi_V(U\cap V)\rightarrow \phi_U(U\cap V) $$

is a diffeomorphism. Remark that we already know that this is a homeomorphism but because $\phi_V(U\cap V)$ and $ \phi_U(U\cap V)$ are both included in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can talk about diffeomorphism.

Hence we see that to define a geometric structure on some space $X$ we need to get a structure of topological manifold for $X$ and then require all the transition to respect the geometric structure in question.

That is why the topological manifold is the "primitive notion of geometric structure" it is a tool that allows us to put some significant geometric structure (differentiable, holomorphic...) on a space.

Comment: So locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has nothing to do with the open subset containing a given point having the same topology as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? What does defining a topology on a manifold actually tell us (what information does it provide)?

Comment: @Will, Locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ means in particular that, locally, the manifold "looks like" $\mathbb{R}^n$. My point is that defining on $X$ the structure of a topological manifold is the first step toward more complicated geometric structure on a manifold. It depends on the field you are working on but usually the topology on a manifold does not bring enough information to be usefull.

Comment: So, from a physics perspective, is the whole point of defining a topology on the manifold to ensure that the manifold can be de-constructed into overlapping open subsets that can locally be mapped to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: @Will Yes, and the point of this deconstruction is the (local) construction of functions, vector fields, smooth tensors and so on.. The fact that this is local comes from the fact that only local pieces look like $\mathbb{R}^n$, however the overlapping property allows you to give a "global" meaning to those objects. whence smooth functions, smooth vector fields have a meaning there...

Comment: Ah ok, I think it's starting to make a little more sense now. Thanks for your help.